# How to make an InboxStyle notification expanded by default on Oreo

Tags: android, android-notifications

I created a notification and on Oreo, it is by default collapsed to the title. How can I make it expanded by default so that I can see the lines?

```
    var myInbox = NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
    for (items in items)
    {
        myInbox.addLine(item.title)
    }

    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ChannelId)
            .setSmallIcon(...)
            .setContentTitle("Got news")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(...)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setLights(...)
            .setStyle(myInbox)
```

Comment: Hi, @Damn have you got any workaround for it? As I am also facing this problem :)